# product collection of arbitrary skus

Tags: product, extensions, product-attribute, collection, collection-filtering

I was wonder if there is any extension available that would let me create filterable product collections where the collection is built by sku fro the url. So the url would be something like:

```
/products/custom_collection/sku1/sku2/sku3/sku4/sku5
```

or

```
/products/custom_collection?skus=sku1,sku2,sku3,sku4,sku5
```

And then the page would act like a product category that is filterable by product attributes just like a regular product category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an exact answer to your question.
But I may have a solution to your problem.
I can recommend you [this free extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/rule-products).
It allows you to create product collections based on rules.
The creation of rules is similar to the way you create catalog discount rules.
It also support SEF urls and filters.
It does not allow you to create a collection by specifying skus in the url from frontend, but you can build a lot of collections by specifying the skus in the rule in the backend.
[Full documentation can be found here](https://github.com/tzyganu/rule-products/wiki).
If that does not fit your needs, maybe you can use it as a starting point to build the extension you need.

Comment: Yes I think this could be a good starting point for what I am looking for, thanks.

Comment: I added 2 lines of code in one file and this now does exactly what I want.